# Yii как подружить с phpexcel

Tags: yii, phpexcel

как можно подключить phpexcel и при клике отдавать документ с содержимым из запроса\массива?
вот что пока сделал

---

пробую установить вендором phpexcel

> d:\open\openserver>cd
>   D:\open\OpenServer\domains\localhost\mining\protected
>
> D:\open\OpenServer\domains\localhost\mining\protected>composer require
>   "yiisoft/yii:@stable"
>
> D:\open\OpenServer\domains\localhost\mining\protected>composer require
>   "phpoffice/phpexcel:@stable"
>
> D:\open\OpenServer\domains\localhost\mining\protected>composer require
>   laxu/yii-phpexcel

отсюда 
https://github.com/laxu/yii-phpexcel

но при $model->writeExcelFile(); //\analiz\views\element\admin.php

```
public function writeExcelFile() //\analiz\models\Element.php
{
$manager = Yii::app()->getComponent('yii-phpexcel');
//Create empty instance
$excel = $manager->create();

//Add a header row with a grey background
$headerStyle = array(
    'fill' => array(
        'type' => \PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
        'color' => array('rgb' => 'CCCCCC')
    )
);
$excel->addHeaderRow(
    array(
        'header1',
        'header2',
        'header3'
    ),
    $headerStyle
);

//Add a few rows of data to the document
//Note that addData doesn't care about the actual keys in the data, only the order of values
$data = array(
    array(
        'data1',
        'data2',
        'data3',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Example',
        'moreData' => 'Something'
    )
);

$excel->addData($data);
$excel->save();
```

}

получаю

```
CException
Неправильный алиас "laxu.yii_phpexcel". Убедитесь, что он указывает на существующую директорию или файл.
```

\protected\config\main.php

```
// application components
'components' => array(
    'yii-phpexcel' => array(
        'class' => '\laxu\yii_phpexcel\ExcelManager',
        'savePath' => 'app.files.excel'
    ),
```

как понимаю нужно хитро autoloader настроить, не пойму как

Answer (score 1, accepted):

на самом деле довольно не тривиальная задача настроить автолодер. проще ложить папку с phpexcel рядом со всей папкой yii и обращаться к ней аяксом. 
подробнее здесь http://des1roer.blogspot.ru/2015/09/yii-phpexcel.html