# Как зарегестрировать новый загрузчик в Yii

Tags: php, yii, phpexcel

для работы PHPExcel необходимо отключить загрузчик Yii, а потом подключить. но этот код не работает в версии 1.1.16. при его выполнении выскакивает ошибка что нет файла.

```
 spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
 Yii::import("ext.phpexcel.Classes.PHPExcel", true);
 $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
 spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
```

может как-то можно сделать через другой загрузчик? или прописывать не в контролере а где еще?

### upd

```
$phpexcelPath = Yii::getPathOfAlias('ext.phpexcel.Classes').'/PHPExcel.php';
echo $phpexcelPath;
```

возвращает

> D:\open\OpenServer\domains\localhost\mining\protected\extensions\phpexcel\Classes/PHPExcel.php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что он не грузится вообще в принципе как расширения Yii, import вам не поможет. Используйте Composer.

Comment: вот так пробовал. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/446604/yii-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-phpexcel

Comment: я не понимаю где это подключать

Answer (score 1):

"выскакивает ошибка что нет файла." Какого конкретно файла?

Попробуй записать перед классом контроллера или в методе init.

```
//Отключаем yii-шный загрузчик
spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase', 'autoload'));
//PHPExcel 1.8
//Второй параметр (true) указывает что файл будет загружен принудительно.
Yii::import("ext.phpexcel.Classes.PHPExcel", true);
//PHPExcel загружен, возвращаемся к yii-шному загрузчику.
spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase', 'autoload'));

class FooController extends Controller
{
    public function actionBar()
    {
         $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    }
}
```

Единственным камнем спотыкания тут является путь к файлу PHPExcel.
Проверь, действительно ли по указаному пути:

```
$phpexcelPath = Yii::getPathOfAlias('ext.phpexcel.Classes').'/PHPExcel.php';
echo $phpexcelPath;
```

лежит файл PHPExcel.php.

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'CException' not found in D:\open\OpenServer\domains\localhost\yii\framework\YiiBase.php on line 323

Comment: а в каком файле это прописывать?

Comment: Судя по ошибке,  Yii::import не отработал корректно. Напиши где то var_dump(file_exists(Yii::getPathOfAlias('ext.phpexcel.Classes').'/PHPExcel.php')) , что оно выведет?;